# Cannot convert subArray form json string into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a json string that I have received form some API, which looks like this:

```
[{"id": 2, "title": "Hello world!", "source": "htp://abc.com/hello_world", "blog": "abc.com", "rating": 0, "date": "2014-08-16T15:44:29Z", "tags": ["programming"]}, {"id": 1, "title": "Why we do not fly to space?", "source": "htp://habrahabr.ru/post/233119/", "blog": "habrahabr.ru", "rating": 5, "date": "2014-08-13T15:56:34Z", "tags": ["space", "science", "future"]}]
```

I receive it like this:

```
NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray*)JSONDictionary;

for (int i=0; i<=jsonArray.count-1; i++) {
        NSDictionary *item = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        . . . 
        NSString* tags = [item objectForKey:@"tags"];
        . . . 
}
```

So now I have this NSArray. I can extract everything except tags. 
I have tried:

```
    NSLog(@"Tags: %@", tags);
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                     JSONObjectWithData:[tags dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                     options:kNilOptions
                     error:&error];
```

This gives me exception:

```
-[__NSCFArray dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109399810
2014-08-17 14:45:48.224 ReadLater[38625:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Then, I have tried this:

```
NSArray *strings = [tags componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

This gives me exception:

```
-[__NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1096a6680
2014-08-17 14:50:57.676 ReadLater[38758:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1096a6680'
```

When I print out tags variable, it looks like this:

```
Tags: (
    space,
    science,
    future
)
```

This is everything that I could possibly tell you about this problem. Hope this gives you idea of whats wrong, coz I suspect that I simply don't know something about this particular case.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `[__NSCFArray dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector...`, `[__NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector...` -- Both of those are telling you **it's an array!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tags` is not a string, it is an array. So, to properly get the tags, use this

```
NSArray *tags = [item objectForKey:@"tags"];
```

To get the tag from the first dictionary in your JSON, you would do this

```
NSString *firstTag = tags[0]; //this would be "programming"
```

Comment: Wow. I did not think that I can extract tags directly as NSArray. That is awesome. Thank you very much. I spent whole day on this.

Comment: You can tell because in JSON a square bracket `[` marks an array, a curly brace `{` marks a dictionary, and just quotes `"` marks a string. In your JSON, the `tags` value uses square brackets.

Comment: That is really useful comment.